# How do I modify my Django REST endpoint to automatically create a dependent model when creating the submitted model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using the djangorestframework module to set up an API to update/read my models.  I have these models ...

```
from django.db import models

from address.models import AddressField
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from address.models import State
from address.models import Country


class CoopTypeManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get_or_create(name=name)[0]


class CoopType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    objects = CoopTypeManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name",)


class Coop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    type = models.ForeignKey(CoopType, on_delete=None)
    address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

and I have these view classes ...

```
class CoopList(APIView):
    """
    List all coops, or create a new coop.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        coops = Coop.objects.all()
        serializer = CoopSerializer(coops, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CoopSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CoopDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a coop instance.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Coop.objects.get(pk=pk)
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        coop = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = CoopSerializer(coop)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        coop = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = CoopSerializer(coop, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        coop = self.get_object(pk)
        coop.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Problem is, I would like to submit JSON like this

```
{
        "name": "1872",
        "type": {
            "name": "Coworking Space"
        },
```

with the intention being that for the dependent CoopType model, I would either create one of use an existing one before creating my Coop model.  However, right now, submitting the above results in a 400 response ...

```
{"type":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."]
```

How should I modify my view class to accommodate what I'm trying to do?

**Edit:** the serializers ...

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from maps.models import Coop, CoopType
from address.models import Address, AddressField, Locality, State, Country


class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'type', 'address', 'enabled', 'phone', 'email', 'web_site']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['type'] = CoopTypeSerializer(instance.type).data
        rep['address'] = AddressSerializer(instance.address).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Coop.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Coop` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.type = validated_data.get('type', instance.type)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.enabled = validated_data.get('enabled', instance.enabled)
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.save()
        return instance


class CoopTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CoopType
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return CoopType.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**Edit 2:** The curl request ...

```
#!/bin/bash

read -d '' req << EOF
{
        "name": "1872",
        "type": {
            "name": "Coworking Space"
        },
        "address": {
            "id": 1,
            "street_number": "222",
            "route": "1212",
            "raw": "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212",
            "formatted": "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212",
            "latitude": 41.88802611,
            "longitude": -87.63612199,
            "locality": {
                "id": 29,
                "name": "Chicago",
                "postal_code": "60654",
                "state": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "IL",
                    "code": "",
                    "country": {
                        "id": 484,
                        "name": "United States",
                        "code": "US"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "phone": null,
        "email": null,
        "web_site": "http://www.1871.com/"
}
EOF

echo $req

curl -v --header "Content-type: application/json" --data "$req" --request POST "http://127.0.0.1/coops/"
```

Comment: What does your serializer look like? And have you looked at the documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers?

Comment: Hi @schillingt, added the serializers as an edit to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class CoopTypeField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    queryset = CoopType.objects

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if type(data) == dict:
            cooptype, created = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**data)
            # Replace the dict with the ID of the newly obtained object
            data = cooptype.pk
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = CoopTypeField()
    # ... the rest of this class is unchanged
```

Where the changes are:

1. Define a custom `CoopTypeField()`. The `to_internal_value()` method would ordinarily be expecting an ID - so we override it to accept data in the form of a dictionary and convert this to an ID (by getting or creating a `CoopType`) and then pass this ID to the parent class method.
2. Define a `type` on the `CoopSerializer` that uses this new `CoopTypeField()`.

Now your `CoopSerializer` will accept data in two forms:

```
{'name': 'Coop 1', 'web_site': 'http://example.com', 'type': {'name': 'Coop Type 1'}}
```

or

```
{'name': 'Coop 1', 'web_site': 'http://example.com', 'type': 1}
```

(I've omitted the other fields that `Coop` requires for brevity).

Comment: Why are you passing "queryset=CoopType.objects.all()" to the member field?  Are we running a full table scan each time an object is created?

Comment: The constructor for that class requires a `queryset` argument to tell it which set of objects it is allowed to use. No, this doesn't run a full table scan - [querysets are evaluated lazily](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), and it gets filtered to a specific ID when you actually query the database.

Comment: I've edited the answer to move the queryset to the class definition itself - just to make it obvious that nothing gets queried at runtime.

Comment: Thanks!  This is looking real promising.  Going to run a few more tests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current serializer, the `CoopType` needs to be made ahead of time (or fetched ahead of time if it exists) so that the id can be passed along. If you want to still make the `CoopType` with nested data in the `Coop` serializer (or use it to find the `CoopType` to use), Django Rest Framework talks about how in their docs under [Writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy... There is so much we could improve upon here. So let's start with your question first.

@tredzko(https://stackoverflow.com/a/60310659/3627387) was right and you should look into https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

By the look of your `CoopType` model I see that `name` field is `unique`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from maps.models import Coop, CoopType
from address.models import Address, AddressField, Locality, State, Country


class CoopTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CoopType
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # type field should be defined here instead of `to_representation`
    type = CoopTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'type', 'address', 'enabled', 'phone', 'email', 'web_site']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # this is the correct way of extending to_representation
        # we set update self.fields and after that
        # Serializer class handles everything automatically
        self.fields['address'] = AddressSerializer(read_only=True)
        return super().to_representation(instance)

    def validate_type(self, value):
        coop_type, __ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**coop_type_data)
        return coop_type
```

Something along this lines should work.

Now let's dive into other improvements

I suggest using `ModelViewSet`(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

So you could do this(see below) instead of your views code

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class CoopViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CoopSerializer
    queryset = Coop.objects.all().select_related('type')
```

Your `CoopType` model is defined in an odd way, I think you wanted to actually do this.

```
class CoopType(models.Model):
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#unique
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        pass
```

Comment: Hi, Why did you replace "unique_together = ("name",)" with "pass"?  I want the unique constraint in my model so that when I create my migration a unique constraint is created in the db to indicate that the "name" field should be unique.

Comment: @Dave Hi. Yes, I understood that, but `unique_together` is constraint for multiple fields. If you want it for one field `unique=True` on field declaration is enough. This is what I did.